# android custom view for notification

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

i want to add a view in my application which has to be clickable, i've tried a dialog but it block the execution of the game, i've also tried to add a view to the WindowManager but it's not clickable. How can i create a "banner like" view?

Comment: what kind of view did you add?  Many types of views allow you set an on click handler to do something.

Comment: I want to add a simple view with a logo and a text. This view has to be clickable.. something like a banner

Comment: Could you post your existing layout xml if you have one?

Comment: it's a simple linearlayout with an imageview and two textview

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to have a `banner view` floating above your game view. Try using `FrameLayout`. Following is a sample xml, hope it can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Replace this with your banner -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Replace this with your game view"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is not the deisgn of the view. I don't have a fixed view where to display the banner. I want to display it sometimes in one activity sometimes in another one. Something like a dialog but it must not be block the execution of the caller view

Comment: You mentioned that you have added a view to WindowManager, did you try `View.setClickable`?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work, i think that the problem is that i've added the view as WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
if i don't set the params like that the app crashes due to badtockenexception

Comment: Maybe you should post some of you codes, so that other guys can understand your problem and help you.